# SEO for dynamically generated content in SPA (single page application) using node.js + express.js on server side

Tags: node.js, express, knockout.js, seo, single-page-application

My client side code is a single page app (written in knockout.js) with its own routing system so when google crawler bot will try to access links (that have nothing to do with requesting new page from back end BUT just a part of client side  routing) it will ask server (node.js + express.js) to serve page (for example 'mywebsite/about') and of course server will return 404 because it unawares of client routing system. Here is my current server code:

```
router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('../dist/index.html'));
});
```

My idea is to define the same routing structure as in a client and pass routs for client routing system in search parameter:

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('../dist/index.html?tab=about'));
});
```

then in client side I can catch it in javascript and pick correct route.
Here off course I have another problem - as I understand google bot doesn't run javascript.. but here I can use [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) middleware I guess.

1) Is it a right way to go with single page apps with generated content and SEO?

2) How to pass search parameter from express.js?

Comment: Using prerender.io you shouldn't declare client-side routes in the server, because it runs javascript before serving the static (prerendered) version of your app.

A very good solution should be to make your application universal. Try to have a look on: https://medium.com/@mjackson/universal-javascript-4761051b7ae9#.s39fzaj0k

Comment: @Hitmands, right, but crawler bot will see a link and ask my server to serve linked page. And here is the problem because my server knows only index.html and knows nothing about client side routs. so on every link request crawler will get (from server) the same index.html page.

Comment: But this is the expected behaviour, your server must serve always the index and then, using prerender, you should be able to handle client-side routes... Probably isn't correct the order of your prerender.io middleware!

Comment: @Hitmands, but still, if server passes index.html to prerender.io, middleware will prerender just index.html (home page) and not my about page. It means that I need to tell prerender.io which route to prerender? Am I right? Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: you need to set prerender.io as first middleware for your requests, basically each request should be intercepted by prerender...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prerender.io as first middleware of your pipe:

`app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'YOUR_TOKEN'));
 app.get('*', (req, res) => res.render('index.html'))`;

Comment: hm, cool.. didn't know that its managed automatically. But how can I verify that mysite/about request was actually intercepted and prerender.io returns correctly prerendered html to google bot?

Comment: You need to simulate a crawling-request, using the crawler user agent and then check if your page is static-html!

Comment: thx for the valuable info. is there a way to do it on my localhost? simulate how?

Comment: You need to create a test-case using something like that module: https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler , personally I never used before... Hope it will be easy to implement!

Comment: could you please see what did I get with all of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856296/seo-with-express-js-and-prerender-node

Answer (score 4):

If you have query strings that Googlebot can use to recall consistent content then you can indicate this in Webmaster:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?rd=1

Here's an example set up of mine:
[image]

Google wants to only index pages that have consistent content. If content varies for each user - then you want to set a rel="canonical" tag on each page indicating where the 'start' would be for this dynamically generated content.

The idea would be to adapt the Webmaster to your app rather than the other way around. Trying to 'trick' the bot can have dire consequences in SEO because Google does have human checkers that occasionally rate domains. If they find inconsistency between the search indexed URL and what they see in their browser, you'll earn a flag from a lazy operator. Here is [the handbook operators follow](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//insidesearch/howsearchworks/assets/searchqualityevaluatorguidelines.pdf).