# SEO with express.js and prerender-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, seo, prerender

**Front-end:**

I have SPA client website that uses own routing system. For instance it has route `http://localhost:8080/about`

**Back-end:**

I'm using prerender-node on express.js server (runs on port 3001) to prerender static html for crawler bots:

```
app.use(require('prerender-node')
    .set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'http://localhost:3000/')
    .set('afterRender', function (err, req, prerender_res) {
        console.log('URL: ', req.url); // here I see: "/about?_escaped_fragment_="
    }));
```

my express routing looks like this:

```
router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('../frontend/dist/index.html'));
});
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that if I send `http://localhost:3001/about?_escaped_fragment_=` to the server as a response I get static index.html home page (but I wanted to prerender about section).

As I understand prerender-node middleware doesn't know how to navigate to /about section and prerenders always home page.

**Question:**

How to prerender the actual about page of my SPA according to a link?

Comment: have a look at: https://prerender.io/documentation/test-it, there are many suggestions. I don't understand what you're getting wrong!

Comment: @Hitmands, well its not clear how it possibly can work. Even on my frontend running locally if I type http://localhost:3001/about in url I get 404 because I use pushstate for navigation but this url request means that I have to have about/index.html file in a root (which I don't have).

Comment: You don't have to pass the route to the express/router, you need to pass the request to prerender.io that runs javascript and send back the html result.

If you are going into the `app.get('*', /***/)`... it means that there is something wrong in your configuration, or, at least, you are sending to your app an incorrect userAgentString... If you are accessing to your app via browser/get, for example, it's obvious that express returns empty index. You need to simulate a crawler-request before starting to develop an universal-like rendering.

Comment: Going to localhost:3001/about shouldn't give you a 404 since you have a catch-all route on the server that should serve the index.html no matter what the URL looks like. If prerender-node is run before your catch-all route, then it should detect the escaped fragment parameter and send that request to be prerendered.

Comment: @Prerender.io, that's what I expect BUT if I go to localhost:3001/about in my browser I still can see prerender_res response in afterRender event and prerender_res.body gives my html page which appears to be just index.html page without additional stuff that should be present on /about section; To be clear 404 I've got in another local server that uses no router.get('*', ... stuff

Comment: Do you still see all of your <script> tags in the html that appears to be your index.html? I'm wondering if perhaps PhantomJS is having trouble rendering your page if there's a javascript error or something. Do see any requests being sent to your local Prerender server if you look at the console?

Comment: @Prerender.io i did solve the issue it was in front-end that was always set path to home after initialization.

Comment: Great! Send us an email if you have any other issues. We're always happy to help.